# What is the difference between class coverage and line coverage while running unit tests in Android Studio?

Tags: android, unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit

When I am running the test classes for my code on Android Studio, I have come across three kinds of coverage.

1. Class Coverage
2. Method Coverage
3. Line Coverage

While method coverage is fairly straightforward to me, I do not understand the difference between line and class coverage. How is class coverage calculated? Is there a formula that takes different metrics into account? How can I improve my class coverage if it has nothing to do with line coverage?

Answer (score 0):

Class coverage includes all classes in the package of class you're being tested.
If you don't use other classes when you run test cases then it will show 0% class coverage of those classes.

Suppose you've 2 classes in the package ***app***

```
-app
  -ClassA.java
  -ClassB.java
```

for test

```
-app
  -ClassATest.java
```

If you run test cases of ClassATest.java then you'll get `Class coverage 50%(1/2)`.
Since both classes are in the same package, it included ClassB too.

Here's the funny part, if you create a `ClassB` object in any test case and run the same `ClassATest` cases again then you'll get `Class coverage 100%(2/2)` since you've used both classes.

Line coverage covers the actual lines of code. IntelliJ marks all the lines Green & Red for Covered & Uncovered respectively, so you can check that easily which lines it has considered.